# CakePHP 2.9 encoded Chars in URL returns Bad Request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP app and need to be able to set special chars like % as get parameter in a url

i encode it correctly to "%25" but revice an error "Bad Request".
Encoding my url twice(to %2525 for example) however works fine....

I tried other solutions posted here like changing the /app/webroot/.htaccess to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,B,L]
</IfModule>
```

but no success so far.

the error already happens befor the index.php in app/webroot is called so i assume its a htaccess error

root and /app .htaccess are configured based on cakePHP's docs (https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

Comment: Apache url decodes before rewriting - hence the observed behavior. `but revice an error "Bad Request"` Unless requests like `/favicon.ico?x=%25` result in a bad request (seems unlikely) the source of the bad request error is code - please debug and put what is responsible for it in the question. `so i assume its a htaccess error` if it really is this, enable debug logging and find a relevant error message to put in the question.

Comment: We workarrounded it by switching to NGINX as webserver, there was no way to stop this behavior of Apache2, well Nginx runns faster and with the expected behavior so win win.